# WorkManager worker not running every hour

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I've created a worker that should run each hour:

```
val workRequest =
    PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(
            Constraints.Builder()
            .build()
        )
        .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
    "myworker",
    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
    workRequest
)
```

Code of the worker itself, it just logs the time it was run to a file:

```
class MyWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val TAG = MyWorker::class.java.simpleName
    private val logPath = appContext.filesDir.absolutePath + "/MyWorker.txt"
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun doWork(): Result {

        return try {
            val timestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())
            File(logPath).appendText("$timestamp MyWorker running")
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MyWorker error: ${e.message}")
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

I had this running for 3 days and the output looks like this:

```
2023-05-18T17:04:37.332722Z MyWorker running
2023-05-18T18:04:37.455146Z MyWorker running
2023-05-18T19:12:09.134985Z MyWorker running
2023-05-18T20:13:09.864851Z MyWorker running
2023-05-18T21:13:59.582659Z MyWorker running
2023-05-18T23:08:43.616284Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T00:10:01.138234Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T01:11:27.086656Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T02:13:01.016104Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T03:14:01.010321Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T04:15:00.933294Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T05:17:24.332208Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T19:22:15.879480Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T20:22:24.040237Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T21:22:43.603717Z MyWorker running
2023-05-19T23:06:25.689580Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T00:07:00.570190Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T01:08:00.482231Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T03:11:02.006581Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T06:00:01.815230Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T09:25:55.780180Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T13:10:53.422335Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T14:17:31.603962Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T15:38:32.328382Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T16:39:41.937991Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T18:13:53.253722Z MyWorker running
2023-05-20T20:22:34.081468Z MyWorker running
```

Instead of each hour there are often much larger gaps. So, how can I run a worker each hour? Why does it run like that? Doen't have to be exact to the minute, but should be at least roughly each hour.

Comment: "Why does it run like that?" -- at minimum, you can be affected by [Doze mode and app standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). Manufacturer-specific mods [can also mess with apps trying to do background work](https://dontkillmyapp.com/).

Comment: Try to run the WorkManger as foreground service, here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75240790/9851608) that probably help