# Worker class enqueued with enqueueUniquePeriodicWork stops working

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I have a Worker class - `public class UpdatePushRegistration extends Worker` which I enqueue using

```
PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdatePushRegistration.class, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
.build();

WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("UpdatePushNotification", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE,myWorkRequest);
```

When I run in the debugger and leave my laptop running, it seems to be working fine. when I run on my phone (either by copying the APK or by publishing through the store) it runs a number of times, sometimes as low as 2, and then stops (I write to a cloud based log). I tried this on two different phone models.

Any idea why this would stop or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: This can depend on the phone model / brand. If you're using any of something like Xiaomi, Huawei, Oppo etc... the system might block the worker after a while to optimize the battery. Each device has its unique solution for this: in Xiaomi you can disable the battery saver option for example. Without that, it is impossible to guarantee unless the phone manufacturer explicitly allows your app by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why this would stop or how to troubleshoot?

Probably because it's a long running worker, in such case the documentation provides [Support for long-running workers](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running) which runs a foreground service on your behalf to execute the `WorkRequest`.

This requires to call [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker#setforeground) to update the notification associated with the foreground service:

> These APIs allow developers to specify that this WorkRequest is
> important (from a user perspective) or long-running.

The documentation offers [a Java sample](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running#long-running-java) for that case. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75240790/9851608) also has another Kotlin example.